# C - Return the first non-whitespace character

Tags: c, char, ascii, whitespace

I have been asked to write a function that returns the first non-whitespace character in an inputted string.

It's working when I enter something like "hello" or anything that does not begin with a white space. But when I enter something like "     hello", it returns a white space.

Here is my code:

```
int question6()
{
    printf("Start typing stuff in \n");
    char myChar = returnFirstNonWhite();

    printf("First non-white space character is: %c",myChar);
}

int returnFirstNonWhite()
{
    int ch,temp;
    ch = getchar();
    while (ch != 32)
    {
        temp = ch;
        printf("Found first success %c\n", ch);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider getting a String input in the first place?

Comment: isnt that what the getchar() is for though?

Comment: Well There're more than enough answers already for such a code.

Comment: getchar gets a char, not a string.

Comment: i think this would be a better method as otherwise you would have to deal with buffers and internally a loop would still occur

Comment: Did you want to do this one character at a time, or did you want the user to enter the full string at once "hello<enter>" or "h<enter>", "e<enter>", ... etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ch = getchar();
while (ch == 32)
{
    ch = getchar();
}
return ch;
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy option would be to use `scanf()` instead of `getchar()`. `scanf()` will take a string (so there's no need to loop getting chars) and it will strip off any starting white space, so you just need to grab the first character it has.

```
int returnFirstNonWhite()
{
    char str[50];
    memset(str, '\0', 50);
    scanf("%s", str);
    return str[0];
}
```

so

```
>>      hello
```

will return 104 (ascii 'h')

Answer (score 0):

At first you are taking only one character input. And if it is not equal to 32 int value, the program should be in a infinite loop!!!! This is a nothing code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything here appears to be okay, except in your `while` loop you don't continue to fetch the next character. In other words, it fetches the initial character, let's say a whitespace, and then continues in that `while` loop forever since the `ch` variable is never changed.

Try adding `ch = getchar();` within your while loop so it continually fetches the next character to check. Also, I just realized you need to check that the character is *equal* to 32, not *not equal* so that if the character is a whitespace it continues to fetch the next character.